# Task crash in Xamarin.iOS simulator debug mode

Tags: xamarin, mono, xamarin.ios

I'm using a *mobile app test* binding library in my project.

When I deploy my project in **Simulator with Debug Mode** app will crash when launch.

But when I deploy my project in **Release Mode** or **iPhone**, everything is OK.

```
// 1. Success
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.WriteLine("After Delay Thread");

// 2. Fail
await Task.Delay(1000);
Console.WriteLine("After Delay Task");
```

What's going on behind this?

[Project Link](https://github.com/KanLei/Task-Crash-In-Xamarin.iOS-Simulator-Debug)

[image]

**Update**

[Diagnostic Reports](https://github.com/KanLei/Task-Crash-In-Xamarin.iOS-Simulator-Debug/blob/master/BugtagsDemo_2016-04-24-224646_Share.crash)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What's the Output after the crash?

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe Only `BUGTAGS: Bugtags v1.2.4(0408) started successfully` and `After Delay Thread`. That's very strange, can you try my project demo again. I update it.

Comment: I just ran your project in a Simulator in Debug mode, works fine.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Thank you, I really don't know why. Add a mov in the project.

Comment: Try resetting the simulator and clean your project.

Comment: Do not work, also tried restart computer, reset and switch to different simulator version.

Comment: What version of Xamarin are you on?

Comment: Look at the crash log and post it ...

Comment: @Softlion The crash log is very long, I put it in the project.